# Need to convert std::vector<ButtonElement> buttonList to std::vector<BYTE> byteVector

Tags: c++, stl

I need to convert std::vector buttonList to std::vector byteVector.
I did it using this
memcpy(&byteVector, &buttonList, buttonList.size() * sizeof(TenderButtonList_Element));

But one of my seniors mentioned that it is not proper usage of STL but didn't say exactly what it is. I suspect that memcpy should not be used on vectors. Is the above conversion valid, I observed that it served its purpose but wanted to know if it is valid or not. If it isn't, can you point the correct way.

Comment: It's not valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If it isn't, can you point the correct way.

That depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

You have a sequence (a `vector`) of `TenderButtonList_Element`, right?

You're looking to produce a sequence of bytes containing the same bit pattern as the first sequence?  Is that correct?

If that is what you're after, then you want something like this:

```
vector<std::byte> vBytes;
vBytes.resize(buttonList.size() * sizeof(TenderButtonList_Element));
memcpy(vBytes.data(), buttonList.data(), vBytes.size());
```

If you want something else, then you'll need to say what that is.

Note that, in general, `memcpy`-ing c++ objects around does not produce valid objects.

Comment: `vBytes.size();`

Comment: Thanks for the response, that is what exactly I needed. Can you briefly explain reason behind the Note part: "memcpy-ing c++ objects around does not produce valid objects"

Comment: An example: A vector contains a pointer to some allocated memory. This is allocated (roughly speaking) in the constructor, and freed in the destructor.  If you memcpy a vector into another vector, you have two objects referring to the same allocated memory, each one believing that it should deallocate that memory when it is destructed.